# What is the difference between dual CT and spectral CT?

Tags: definition, x-rays

I'm reading about different types of CT scans and I'm frequency seeing the words "Dual x-ray CT" and "Spectral x-ray CT" being used to describe different things but I can't find a single explanation about the difference between these two things.

Can someone give an explicit explanation about the difference between a dual x-ray CT and a spectral x-ray CT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual X-ray CT is just x-ray at two different energies. You get some physiological information from the different amount of absorption at each wavelength/energy  eg. measuring bone mineralisation.

Spectral x-ray CT just extends this to a range of energies. In clinical use they don't really have a true spectral imaging , typically just 4 or 8 energy bands. In theory this should give you more information - but if the energies are all very similar and the noise increases because you are splitting the received power into more detectors it might be more of a marketing benefit

Comment: So by "extends this to a range of energies", do you mean it's more than two x-ray energies or it's two ranges of energies?

Comment: It is a single range of energies - with discrete detectors at each energy